# Mocking function imported at the top of the file

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest

I am trying to do a test in a project, and I am having an weird error.

I reproduced the very similar situation with the toy example below:

This is the file structure:

```
.
├── some_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_file.py
└── test_mock_patch.py
```

```py
"""some_package/some_file.py"""

# when I import here, the test fails
from math import floor


def some_func(a, b):
    # if I import here, the test passes
    # from math import floor
    return floor(a + b)
```

```py
"""test_mock_patch.py"""

import pytest
from unittest import mock
from some_package.some_file import some_func


@pytest.fixture
def mock_floor():
    with mock.patch('math.floor', autospec=True) as m:
        yield m


def test_some_func(mock_floor):
    some_func(1.1, 1)
    assert mock_floor.call_count == 1
```

Command used: `pytest -v -s test_mock_patch.py`

The error:

[image]

Why when I import inside the function the `test_some_func` passes and when I import at the top the test fails?

Thank you in advance for any help to explain this behaviour of `mock.patch`

Versions:

- Python 3.7.3
- pytest 4.4.1

Comment: you need to mock `some_package.some_file.math.floor` since that is where it's being imported from, although if you are using `pytest` you should be using the `monkeypatch` fixture

Comment: but why when I import inside the function it works?

Comment: because you're importing it in the same file so it knows where to look

Comment: How would you use `monkeypatch` instead of `mock.patch` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example how to achieve the desired result by changing your `test_mock_patch.py` file.

```
import pytest
from some_package.some_file import some_func


def test_some_func(monkeypatch):
    with monkeypatch.context() as mc:
        mc.setattr('some_package.some_file.floor', lambda x: 'foo')
        res = some_func(1.1, 1)
        assert res == 'foo'
```

Like I mentioned in the comments, you need to patch the function where it is being imported.